# Designed a extension by c++ for PHP, I got some error

Tags: php, c++, apache

I designed an extension by c++ for PHP. When I run an extension-related method, there occurred a PHP error. I found this **/var/log/apache2/error.log** file;
But already I am running a similar type of extension in my system.

PHP version: 7.2.34
operation system: ubuntu 18.04
Zend Engine v3.2.0

### error :

> [Wed Apr 07 20:01:58.215958 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32197] AH00051: child pid 32198 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
> [Wed Apr 07 20:01:58.216005 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32197] AH00051: child pid 32199 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
> [Wed Apr 07 20:01:59.218515 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32197] AH00051: child pid 32200 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
> [Wed Apr 07 20:01:59.218573 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32197] AH00051: child pid 32201 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
> [Wed Apr 07 20:01:59.218589 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32197] AH00051: child pid 32202 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Has anyone seen similar before? Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Hi @NurHossen a core dump is generally caused the program not doing something correct and interacting incorrectly with memory - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321512/what-is-a-core-dump-file-in-linux-what-information-does-it-provide .. can you write a snippet that produces the same problem outside of PHP .. then you might be able to ask for help [basically anything doing something wrong with memory will possibly core dump]

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I got my problem that was a data type-related problem in the CPP site.
Prevoiusly I used this:
`if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a|l", &arr_hash1, &org_flag) == FAILURE) {
}`
Heare HashTable *arr_hash1; but I used as like array, Now we find my problem and solve this by  "h|l" instated of  "a|l"
`if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "h|l", &arr_hash1, &org_flag) == FAILURE) {
}`