# How to solve exit code 139 error when reading from file on unix

Tags: c, unix

So I believe this is just a problem on unix and that it occurs at the first fscanf if the Clion debugger was right, but I don't know why I get the error- Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) - why?

```
struct loginInformation
{
    char username[USERNAME_LENGTH];
    char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH];
    int type;
}accounts[NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS];

void createAccountsFromFile()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("accounts.txt", "r");
    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS; counter++)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%s", accounts[counter].username);
        fscanf(input, "%s", accounts[counter].password);
        fscanf(input, "%d", &accounts[counter].type);
    }
}

int main()
{
    createAccountsFromFile();
}

accounts.txt

user1
pass1
0
user2
pass2
1
user3
pass3
2
user4
pass4
3
```

Comment: check 1)  return value of `fopen`. (Is the file in a relative path accessible? Or do you have access authority?...). 2) Is there data that causes buffer overflow in reading?

Comment: this line: `for(counter = 0; counter < NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS; counter++)` contains the assumption that there will be exactly `NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS` accounts in the input file.  That is a very 'iffy' assumption.  Much better to use something like: `counter =0; while( fscanf( input, "%s", accounts[counter].username) == 1)`  however, even that is weak because any one line may not contain all three data items. AND '%s" can overflow the input buffer, Which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: Lets say that USERNAME_LEN is 20 for the following:  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions,1) always check the returned value, not the parameter value to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the '%s' input/conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any buffer overflow.  I.E.  `if( fscanf(input, " %19s", accounts[counter].username) != 1 ) { perror( "fscanf for user name failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: @user3629249 To further clarify, NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS = 4, and their are 12 lines of text in the text file, is fscanf reading line by line here

Comment: @michaellee If file is accessible then there should not be any issue with  'fopen'; but in your program you have to close the file descriptor as 'fclose(input)'.

Comment: @user3629249: Note that in general, `fscanf()` can return 0 which means there was no error to be reported by `perror()`, but the input data didn't match the conversion specification.  With a string, pretty much anything is OK, so that won't be a problem, but with numeric conversion specifications, it definitely can be (the user types `z` instead of a digit, for example).

Comment: when `fscanf()` returns 0 that means that the 'first'  input/conversion specification failed.  It does NOT mean there was no error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the program crashed before it exited. You need to debug the program. For example, you need to check whether the file is successfully opened after `fopen`.

Comment: Yeah, the file wasn't opening. I had to specify the working directory by editing the configuration, then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Your program tried to access a memory location it had no permissions to access, so the operating system killed it.

---

First: The code "139" doesn't matter, forget about the number. Your program was terminated after "getting a SIGSEGV", or a signal regarding a segmentation violation. Read about what that means here:

[What causes a SIGSEGV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564372/what-is-sigsegv-run-time-error-in-c)

(never mind that question is about C++, same idea.)

Now, why would this happen? You must be making some assumptions you shouldn't be. Looking at your code, it might be:

- Reading a very long string from the file which exceeds the bounds of the `loginInformation` array - and perhaps even the bounds of the memory region allocated to your program overall.
- Scanning from an invalid-state/uninitialized/null file descriptor, as in @xuhdev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42882179/1593077)
- (Unlikely/impossible) Ignoring some error generated by one of the `fscanf()` calls (you need to check `errno` if a scan failed).

I think that covers it although maybe I missed something. Instead of speculating you can actually check what happened using a debugger on the [core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775872/why-are-core-dump-files-generated):

[How do I analyze a program's core dump file with GDB when it has command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb)

Comment: The code "139" is generally standard for file access.  While the content of this post is good, this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @BAMF4bacon: Standard in what sense?

Comment: It is standard for SIGSEGV in LSF, exit codes are Signal + 128, SIGSEGV is 11, 128+11=139

Answer (score 2):

SIGSEGV are not always thrown due to a root cause of memory access problems...

Perl throws a 139 on Unix usually because of file I/O.  You might have accidentally deleted your input files.

Answer (score -1):

On Perl programmation RC 139 caused by "Out of memory" for me.
Because there have been too much data in a variable (millions).
I have done a segmentation manualy by release (undef) this variable regularly.
This solved this.